# Typescript - Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type {object}

Tags: typescript, object, destructuring

I have a function that returns an object like this:

```
  const sale: saleObject = {
    pxa:  {
      xano: data.xano,
      storeno: data.storeno,
      pdvno: data.pdvno,
      date: data.pxa.date,
      time: data.pxa.time,
      xatype: data.pxa.date,
      there_is_nf: data.pxa.there_is_nf,
      paymno: data.pxa.paymno
    },
    pxanf: {
      xano: data.xano,
      storeno: data.storeno,
      pdvno: data.pdvno,
      issuedate: data.pxanf.issuedate,
      tipo: data.pxanf.tipo,
      paymno: data.pxanf.paymno
    },
  };
```

I want to destructure it. But when i'm destructuring i'm getting the error:

```
 const {pxa, pxanf, pxanf2, pxaprd, xaprd2, xaprd3}: saleObject = saleTransformation(req);

Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'saleObject': pxa, pxanf, pxanf2, pxaprd, and 2 more.
```

"saleObject" is an interface with the same fileds of the object above.

How can i fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  I cannot tell what `saleTransformation()` does, nor what `req` is, nor what `data` is, so I cannot advise you. And the actual `saleObject` interface would be nice (especially since `data` is not defined here).  Apparently `saleTransformation(req)` returns an object known only to not be `null` or `undefined`, so the compiler cannot safely destructure it as a `saleObject`.  But without more information I can only guess.  Good luck!